# How to proper configure PHPunit in PhpStorm

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework2, phpstorm

I have a problem with configuration of PHPunit in PHPStorm. 
I'm using Windows7 as OS and mostly Zend Framework 2.
Here is a structure of my project:

```
/module
    /Application
        /tests
            /ApplicationTest
                /Controller
                    /ApplicationControllerTest.php
            Bootstrap.php
            phpunit.xml.dist
            TestConfig.php.dist
    /Album
        /tests
            /AlbumTest
                /Controller
                    /AlbumControllerTest.php
                /Album
                    /AlbumModelTest.php
            Bootstrap.php
            phpunit.xml.dist
            TestConfig.php.dist
```

Currently to check specyfic module I need to edit my Run/Debug Configuration in PHPStorm. I have to select "Use alternative configuration file" option and enter path to PHPunit config file.
 Is there any way to automatize this process?
  It would be nice if I didn't have to enter path to config file for every model.
Thanks for any tips

Comment: Few possible approaches: **1)** `Setting | PHP | PHPUnit | **DEFAULT** configuration file` **2)** Edit entries under **Defaults** branch  (`Run | Edit Configurations...`). When creating **new** Run/Debug Configuration, fields will be pre-filled with default values from there.

Comment: @LazyOne If I set in Settings->PHP->PHPUnit path to Application/tests/phpunit.xml.dist then when I'll want run tests for Album I get error bcuz it loads configuration from Application/tests/ while it should loads from Album/tests/

Comment: Well.. I gave you the options--it's up to you to choose the best one that suits you. You can simply have separate projects (for Application and Album) - in this case you will not have such problem. Unfortunately you cannot have **multiple/different** defaults in the same project based on your folder name or something (in this case it will NOT be defaults at all). Instead of creating new run configuration from scratch all the time.. why not use "copy" of existing one? All what you have to do later is to change name/tested class etc. At the end of the day--you do not create new one every 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Check Tutorial [Creating PHPUnit Tests in PhpStorm](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Creating+PHPUnit+Tests+in+PhpStorm):

> The easiest way to create a test is to invoke the action "New ..." (Context menu on folder/file in the Project View, or File | New, or Cmd-N / Alt+Insert keystroke) and select New | PHPUnit | PHPUnit Test.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on your PHPUnit configuration file in the project browser and choose **Run...** in the context menu.

After that, the configuration file appears in the configuration menu. Go to **Run** > **Edit configurations**... Select your configuration file in the tree at the left of the dialog, then click sur **Save configuration** in the toolbar.